# .htaccess redirect root to one file, all other files to another

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2 domains using the same webspace, `originaldomain.com` and `newdomain.com`

I have placed a .htaccess file at the root of `newdomain.com` so that if visitors go to it, it shows (but masks) the url of:

`originaldomain.com/script.php`

I can get something similar using the following rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.originaldomain.com/script.php [P]
```

However, style sheets, images and javascript are not loading. I assume one of two things:

1. They are not applicable to the mod_rewrite rule and are not found
   when originaldomain.com/item1.jpg is being searched for at
   newdomain.com/item1.jpg
2. All files may be subject to having a php file stuffed before their
   name, so that originadomain.com/item.jpg is now being looked for at
   newdomain.com/portfolio.phpimage1.jpg

I'm looking to create a situation where:

- If somebody visits `newdomain.com/?variables` it masks and loads
  `originaldomain.com/script.php?variables`
- If somebody visits `www.newdomain.com/?variables` it masks and loads
  `originaldomain.com/script.php?variables`
- All other file requests from the root of `newdomain.com` are pointed to
  relative links at `originaldomain.com`, so that
  `http://newdomain.com/css/stylesheet.css` is loaded and masked from
  `http://originaldomain.com/css/stylesheet.css`

Any input appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From trial and error, this appears to be working at the moment:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.originaldomain.com/script.php [P]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.originaldomain.com/script/$1 [P]
```